# piped command after grep not working

Tags: grep, buffer

I want to monitor a file. So I have tailed a file using below command, to execute a script per line.

```
tail -3f logfile.log | grep "action.*add" | sed -u -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/" | xargs -L 1 -P 5 bash testscript.sh
```

But it seems that script is not getting executed. 
I observed that `grep` is not giving any input for next pipe.

When I tried,

```
tail -3f logfile.log | grep "action.*add"
```

it worked. But when given next filter like `sed`, `grep`, `xargs` etc. It didn't worke like the one shown below.

```
tail -3f /var/tmp/rabbitmq-tracing/logfile.log | grep "action.*add" | grep add
```

Please help me to know why this is happening and how to overcome this.

---

**Edit 1:**
Basically anything like below should work and it was working previously. Confused why it is not working now.

```
tail -f file.txt | grep something | grep something | grep something
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
Output line after first grep will be a json string like below. And I want to give this line as input( enclosed in single quotes) to bash script.

```
{"twNotif": {"originator": "api", "chain": "test", "txId": "08640-0050568a5514", "version": "1.0", "msgType": "api", "twData": {"api": {"hostId": "007bdcc5", "user": "test", "cmdTxt": "100599"}}, "action": "add", "store": "test", "msgTime": 1467280648.971042}}
```

Comment: please post some sample log from your log file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `--line-buffered` switch on `grep`

```
tail -3f logfile.log | grep --line-buffered "action.*add" | sed -u -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/" | xargs -L 1 -P 5 bash testscript.sh
```

from man grep:

> --line-buffered
>                 Use line buffering on output.  This can cause a performance penalty.

---

or you can use `stdbuf`  [read more](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html#stdbuf-invocation)

> stdbuf allows one to modify the buffering operations of the three
>   standard I/O streams associated with a program. Synopsis:

use this syntax:

```
... | stdbuf -oL grep ... | ...
```

your example:

```
tail -3f logfile.log | stdbuf -oL grep "action.*add" | sed -u -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/" | xargs -L 1 -P 5 bash testscript.sh
```

Comment: if I use --line-buffered for grep then sed receives input. But sed do not give any input to next piped command. In such case, do sed have any such option like '--line-buffered'.

Comment: @AVJ , no no! you use -u in sed; -u in sed is equal with --line-buffered in grep !!

Comment: Yeah it worked with -u in sed... But can u just explain why this happened. Because.. for me previously something like below command was working fine. tail -f logfile.log | grep pattern | grep pattern | grep pattern | sed 's/ss/gg/g'

Comment: @AVJ : what is your testscript.bash code?! ,, this this on you pc http://pastebin.com/ix7zyGRY ,, you can see your sed have not problem;

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, `grep`'s line-buffering is the obvious cause of your problem.

However, there are other problems with what you're doing that are not so obvious.

To start with, it looks like you're using `sed` to add apostrophes to the start and end of each output line so you can feed it into `xargs`.  This isn't even remotely necessary - `xargs` has `-d` option you can use to tell it to use newlines as delimiter: e.g. `xargs -d'\n' -r` (the `-r` option is to make sure `xargs` does nothing if there are no input lines)

Secondly, you're using regular expressions to parse json data.  This is unreliable, extremely difficult or even impossible to get right with complex/nested structures, fragile, and prone to break at the drop of a hat for exactly the same reasons that using regexps to parse XML or HTML is unreliable, extremely difficult, and fragile.  Don't parse XML or HTML [with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).  It [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/137158).  **The same applies to json**.

Instead, you should use something like `jq` or `jsonpipe` to extract fields from json data.  For example:

```
jq -c 'select(.twNotif.action == "add")' file.txt | 
  xargs -d'\n' -r -L 1 -P 5 ./testscript.sh
```

If you only wanted to pipe the **value of the action field** to `xargs` (without the double-quotes), you could do it like this:

```
jq 'select(.twNotif.action == "add") | .twNotif.action' file.txt | 
  sed -e 's/"//g' | 
  xargs -d'\n' -r -L 1 -P 5 ./testscript.sh
```

Using `jsonpipe` and `awk` would probably be easier for a job like that:

```
jsonpipe < file.txt | 
  awk '$1 == "/twNotif/action" {gsub(/"/,""); print $2}' |
  xargs -d'\n' -r -L 1 -P 5 ./testscript.sh
```

(note the redirection there, unlike `jq`, `jsonpipe` works only with stdin).

BTW, `jsonpipe` transforms json data into a line-oriented format suitable for using with line-oriented tools like `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, etc.  For example:

```
$ jsonpipe < file.txt
/   {}
/twNotif    {}
/twNotif/originator "api"
/twNotif/chain  "test"
/twNotif/txId   "08640-0050568a5514"
/twNotif/version    "1.0"
/twNotif/msgType    "api"
/twNotif/twData {}
/twNotif/twData/api {}
/twNotif/twData/api/hostId  "007bdcc5"
/twNotif/twData/api/user    "test"
/twNotif/twData/api/cmdTxt  "100599"
/twNotif/action "add"
/twNotif/store  "test"
/twNotif/msgTime    1467280648.971042
```

It's easier to work with than `jq`, especially if you don't need json-formatted output.

It's also useful for listing the structure of and fields/elements in a json file in form that can easily be used with `jq`.  e.g.:

```
$ jsonpipe <file.txt | awk '{gsub(/\//,"."); print $1}'
.
.twNotif
.twNotif.originator
.twNotif.chain
.twNotif.txId
.twNotif.version
.twNotif.msgType
.twNotif.twData
.twNotif.twData.api
.twNotif.twData.api.hostId
.twNotif.twData.api.user
.twNotif.twData.api.cmdTxt
.twNotif.action
.twNotif.store
.twNotif.msgTime
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're likely seeing is "pipeline buffering"; the output of various components of the pipeline (in your case the `grep`) are no longer line buffered but block buffered, and a buffer may be 4K or so  The next component doesn't see data immediately.  It *will* see it when enough data occurs...

The solution is a little painful.  Fortunately the `expect` package comes with a comamnd `unbuffer` which can help.  `man unbuffer` for more details on how to use this.

It works by making components of the pipeline think they are talking to a terminal and so stay line buffered.