# How to use command on output of processed tail -f?

Tags: bash, tail

So I monitor some logs (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`) with the command `tail -f`, and only print the errors (`grep ':error'`).
I combined both of these in a script (namely, `watch_error_log`.)

NB: I am part of the adm group.

So far so good.

But when I attempt more useful tricks, it won't work, such as :

```
$ while read APACHE_DEBUG_LOG; do echo "$APACHE_DEBUG_LOG"; done < <(watch_error_log)
or
$ watch_error_log | while read DEBUG_LOG_APACHE; do echo "$DEBUG_LOG_APACHE"; done;
```

Of course, my goal is not to ECHO the output. But If echo won't work, I know it is not because of the other program I want to use.

Why doesn't it work, and how can I make this work ?

After reading [piped command after grep not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293278/piped-command-after-grep-not-working), I tried to add `--line-buffered` and everything's good.

Comment: so `watch_error_log` essentially contains `tail -f somefile | grep :error`, right?

Comment: indeed works perfectly