# Filtering ping output through multiple pipes fails

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection, ping

Trying to capture only the packets return time from `ping` output, I issued

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1 | grep -o '[^ =]* ms'
```

and it worked, displaying each packet time when it arrived. Since I also wanted to get rid of the unit of time, thought this would suffice:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1 | grep -o '[^ =]* ms' | grep -o '^[^ ]*'
```

But, to my surprise, it hangs, showing no output. Replacing the first command with an `echo` of a sample line from `ping` output, however, works as expected (it outputs `5.07`):

```
$ echo '64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=5.07 ms' | grep -o '[^ =]* ms' | grep -o '^[^ ]*'
```

I found other means of getting only the time without the milissecond unit, but still: What is the issue with `ping` command? Why is passing it through one pipe is OK, but not through two?

PS: These below also fail, while their `echo` versions succeed, thus the problem can't be with `grep`

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1 | grep -o '[^ =]* ms' | sed 's_ ms__'
$ ping 192.168.0.1 | grep -o '[^ =]* ms' | cut -f 1 -d ' '
$ ping 192.168.0.1 | cut -f 7 -d ' ' | cut -f 2 -d '='
```

Comment: Buffering (delayed output until the output buffer of `grep` is filled), not "hanging". If you use GNU `grep`, use it with `--line-buffered`.  This may well be a dupe of [piped command after grep not working](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/293278)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definite answer is [line buffering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/293278/100397). You can demonstrate this with `ping -c 3` instead of just `ping`, where all output is produced only at the completion of the first command.

As a workaround with GNU `grep` you can reduce your two filters to one

```
ping 192.168.0.1 | grep -oP '[[:digit:].]+(?= ms)'
```

Or if you really want to use two filters, either `grep --line-buffered ...` or `stdbuf -oL grep ...` will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by the line buffering of your shell.

If you let your command run long enough, you should see some output.
Or just limit the amount of pings like this:

```
$ ping -c4 192.168.0.1 | grep -o '[^ =]* ms' | grep -o '^[^ ]*'
```

There is some more information and workarounds (solutions?) if you follow this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)